# How to spyOn a property called in a function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I need to spyOn the 'offsetWidth' because the value is now undefined.
getCurrentPage is a function which get the element based on the id currentpage.

The spy on the getCurrentPage works, but I need also to declare the offsetWidth. But that didn't work.

Functions:

```
getCurrentPage() {
    return this.$document[0].getElementById('currentPage');
}

calculateStep() {
    this.stepWidth = this.getCurrentPage().offsetWidth / (this.totalSteps - 1);
    return this.stepWidth;
}
```

Unit test:

```
let stepWidth = new StepController();
stepWidth.totalSteps = 5;

const dummyCurrentPage = '<div id="currentPage" style="width: 20%;"></div>';

spyOn(stepWidth, 'getCurrentPage').and.returnValue(dummyCurrentPage);

const expectedResult = '200 / 4';

const result = stepWidth.calculateStep();

expect(result).toBe(expectedResult);
});
```

How can I spyOn the offsetWidth of this.getCurrentPage().offsetWidth ?

Comment: Is the variable dummyCurrentPage turned into an element? Or does it remain a string?

Comment: @DaniëlW.Crompton it turned in to a string.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, turning the dummyCurrentPage to an angular.element and defining the offsetWidth to the angular.element.

```
const element = angular.element('<div id="currentPage" style="width: 20%;"></div>');

stepWidth.getCurrentPage().offsetWidth = 50;
```